# Internet Explorer 11: Mouseenter Mouseleave issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mouseevent

I am actually working on this [website](http://www.aquila-pratteln.ch/) and i have an issue on internet Explorer.

On the right side of the page (the grey one) there is a button with an "i" icon. This button is a modal and inside the modal window there is a table with "mouseenter mouseleave" on the mouse over the table's rows.

The animation works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox etc but not on the old versions of Internet Explorer.

The toggle function on the last 5 rows does not works.

Any ideas on how can I solve it?

PS: I am using Wordpress

Code:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-2.even", function() {
$('.buro_1').toggle();
}); 

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-3.odd", function() {
$('.buro_2').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-4.even", function() {
$('.buro_3').toggle();
});  

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-5.odd", function() {
$('.buro_4').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-6.even", function() {
$('.buro_5').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-7.odd", function() {
$('.buro_6').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-8.even", function() {
$('.buro_7').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-9.odd", function() {
$('.buro_8').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-10.even", function() {
$('.buro_9').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-11.odd", function() {
$('.buro_10').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-12.even", function() {
$('.buro_11').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-13.odd", function() {
$('.buro_12').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-14.even", function() {
$('.buro_13').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-15.odd", function() {
$('.buro_14').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-16.even", function() {
$('.buro_15').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-17.odd", function() {
$('.buro_16').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-18.even", function() {
$('.buro_17').toggle();
});

$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".tablepress-id-2 .row-19.odd", function() {
$('.buro_18').toggle();
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you have a css who hide your element. Try remove all: (on http://www.aquila-pratteln.ch/wp-content/uploads/js_composer/custom.css?ver=4.12)

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), all and (-ms-high-contrast:active)
.buro_14 {
    display: none !important;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), all and (-ms-high-contrast:active)
.buro_15 {
    display: none !important;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), all and (-ms-high-contrast:active)
.buro_16 {
    display: none !important;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), all and (-ms-high-contrast:active)
.buro_17 {
    display: none !important;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), all and (-ms-high-contrast:active)
.buro_18 {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The rows 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 is already `display:block` try to make this `display:none` too

Work fine with IE9 and more